# Secure REST APIs from non-browser client

Tags: security, rest, client-server, httprequest

I'm developing a web application using Java EE and some open source components (Spring, Struts 2, jQuery, and so on). Some of my web pages require authentication (Spring Security) and other not. I write some REST APIs (Restlet) and I use them from my pages by AJAX calls (jQuery). I know that other web sites can not use my REST APIs unless I enable CORS and this is what I want.

However any non-browser client (curl, Java applications, and so on) can call my REST APIs: how can I forbid this? I can not use authentication for all REST APIs because I use some of them in web pages that should not require authentication. I know that some APIs (like Facebook SDK) require an application-id in order to enable calls, but anyone can steal the key from the Javascript code included in my web pages.

I would like to recognize from the server side if an HTTP request has been sent from a browser or other client applications in order to apply some kind of authentication only in the second case. As I concern, any client application can set any HTTP header, so I can not HTTP headers, can I? I think that my problem should be a common problem, so maybe I miss something.

Answer (score 3):

There's nothing you can do.

Most folks are worried about unauthorized users using their applications. You're worried about unauthorized programs.

Yet everything that a program needs to communicate with your server, it will be told (by the server as in a token, or by the user as in a credential).

Why are you afraid of "non-browser" clients? Why do you care what client they use? How is a non-browser client different than a normal browser for your use cases?

Answer that question, and you'll find better answers.

Are you afraid they'll "screen scrape" your site, quickly download it with something like wget? Then you can put in some server side rule gating their access (if IP x.y.z.w makes more than Q requests per BLEEM of time, then discard request/sleep 10s/send content REALLY slowly).

Those kinds of measures are what you have to do. You can't "secure" the client, it's not your client to secure. You have to secure your server, and address the concerns head on.

Remember rule #1 of client/server design: "Never trust the client". On the internet, no one knows you're a bot.

Comment: Yes, I am worried about DoS attacks and other malware: I am looking for a simple solution I can apply to all of my APIs without headache.